# Bcompiler 1.0.2 does not work if a class is defined

Tags: encoder, bcompiler

The bcompiler encoded script of this code works fine:

```
<?php echo time();
```

However if I just add a class, even without any code within the class, like this:

```
<?php
echo time();
class myClass { }
```

then the encoded script no longer works. I tested on nginx with fastcgi php 5.3.5 (bound to unix socket), and even set up a completely new ubuntu 11.04 server (using VirtualBox) and just install apache 2 and php 5.3.5 as an apache module. In both cases, the browser present the requested script as a file for download, and the content of the downloaded file is empty. If I include the encoded script in server's index.php file and browse http://localhost, an empty page is shown and php logs a "Segmentation fault" error and the php cgi process is killed.

I tested bcompiler 1.0.1 and got same problem. Bcompiler 0.9.3 works fine though. However if I run a bcompiler 0.9.3 encoded script on php with bcompiler 1.0.2 then the problem happens again. So I think it is a problem with bcompiler interpreter. I guess there's something very basic I'm missing about bcompiler version >= 1.0.0

I'm sure there's no error in my encoding code, I also tried bencoder (http://bencoder.urdada.net/) to encode the scripts...